# Makefile, Why is it recompiled every time?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

My directory structure is: `objFile/(cacheOp.o,fileOp.o)` ,`Header/(cacheOp.h,fileOp.h)` ,`Bodyer/(cacheOp.cpp,fileOp.cpp)`
I wrote a Makefile document：

```
cc=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -o0 
libObjs = objFile/cacheOp.o objFile/fileOp.o
all : cacheOpObj testFunc.cpp fileOpObj
    $(cc) testFunc.cpp objFile/cacheOp.o  -o test $(CXXFLAGS)
cacheOpObj : Header/cacheOp.h Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp
    $(cc) -c Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp  -o objFile/cacheOp.o $(CXXFLAGS)
fileOpObj : Header/fileOp.h Bodyer/fileOp.cpp
    $(cc) -c Bodyer/fileOp.cpp -o objFile/fileOp.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

But the result was not as expected.

1. When I execute the `make` command, even if I don't make any changes, it will execute the `g++ -c Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp  -o objFile/cacheOp.o` `g++ -c Bodyer/fileOp.cpp -o objFile/fileOp.o` `g++ testFunc.cpp objFile/cacheOp.o  -o test`.  If the file hasn't changed, shouldn't it show that it is the latest? I named the dependency in the label.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `.PHONY: test`?

Comment: After removing .PHONY: test, it will still recompile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're lying to Make, look at this rule/recipe:

```
cacheOpObj : Header/cacheOp.h Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp
    $(cc) -c Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp  -o objFile/cacheOp.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

This means "if `cacheOpObj` is missing or older than `Header/cacheOp.h` or `Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp`, this command will generate it". Except it doesn't, it creates a file named `objFile/cacheOp.o` instead. So Make re-runs the recipe every time.

You also have a typo in your CXXFLAGS (`-o0` instead of `-O0`) which you should fix. (and `-Og` is a better default anyway)

Here is a cleaned up version of your makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS=-g -Og 
libObjs=objFile/cacheOp.o objFile/fileOp.o

all: test
test: testFunc.cpp $(libObjs)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) 

objFile/cacheOp.o: Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp Header/cacheOp.h 
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
objFile/fileOp.o: Bodyer/fileOp.cpp Header/fileOp.h 
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Note the use of automatic variables such as `$<` (first input), `$^` (all inputs), `$@` (output) to shorten the recipes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a make beginner you should avoid targets that are not real files. In your case, when you type `make` make tries to build the first target: `all`. As there is no such file it knows that the recipe will have to be executed in order to create the file named `all`. But before executing this recipe it looks at the prerequisites (`cacheOpObj`, `testFunc.cpp`, `fileOpObj`). The first and the third don't exist neither so make tries to build them.

Replace all this by:

```
test: objFile/cacheOp.o testFunc.cpp objFile/fileOp.o
    $(cc) testFunc.cpp objFile/cacheOp.o  -o test $(CXXFLAGS)

objFile/cacheOp.o: Header/cacheOp.h Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp
    $(cc) -c Bodyer/cacheOp.cpp  -o objFile/cacheOp.o $(CXXFLAGS)

objFile/fileOp.o: Header/fileOp.h Bodyer/fileOp.cpp
    $(cc) -c Bodyer/fileOp.cpp -o objFile/fileOp.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

See, all targets and prerequisites are real files. Make can check their existence and last modification time to decide what to do.